# Boundary of a cell and its membrane - position definition and jargon problem

Tags: cell-biology, proteins, cell-membrane, definitions

Can extracellular be extramembrane/intramembrane?

Definition of Extracellular [here](https://www.nature.com/subjects/extracellular-matrix):

> Extracellular matrix: The extracellular matrix is a complex network of material such as proteins and polysaccharides that are secreted locally by cells and remain closely associated with them to provide structural, adhesive and biochemical signalling support.

Another definition [here](https://www.uniprot.org/locations/SL-0112):

> The extracellular space is the space outside of the cell membrane but part of a multicellular organism. The term is typically used for a secreted protein that remains associated with the cell, e.g. as part of the extracellular matrix. It is not used for a protein that is secreted into the blood stream (or other body fluids) of eukaryotic, multicellular organisms, such as insulin or fibroblast growth factors.

Not really helpful in clarifying. On Google, various sources tend to give rather conflicting definitions.

This is one definition of Extramembrane found [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3605051/):

> In this study, we find that over 60% of the extramembrane domains were structurally related to proteins of known structure.
> There's no definition or figure of what makes up extramembrane, yet it's been used over in journals.

Consider following scenario in terms of domains of **integral proteins, membrane proteins**, for e.g. loop-1 of A-protein is inside cell but outside membrane(?), helix-1 is inside membrane but outside cell(?), loop-2 is outside cell and outside membrane.

Can we refer to loop-1 as extramembrane and intracellular since it's not within membrane but within the cell? What is the correct reference to this domain?
Can we refer to helix-1 as intracellular (as well as transmembrane)?
Can we refer to loop-2 as extramembrane? extracellular?

What is the corrent way to refer to these 3 positions?

Asking this question becasue there's a real dilemma around holding an accurate understaing understanding and definitions of cell components references/positions and use of the above jargon.

Comment: Neither of those definitions are definitions of "extracellular". One is "extracellular matrix" one is "extracellular space". I think overall you're not really asking a very goal-directed question, what's the problem to solve here? Can you give a specific example where conflicting terminology is used in different places?

Comment: @BryanKrause goal is to know clearly what defines extramembrane and extracellular of a cell, membrane, that consists membrane proteins. e.g. a figure/image showing exactly what comprise of these definitions.

Comment: They are adjectives that mean "outside a membrane" and "outside a cell". Do you know an example where these terms are used inconsistently based on those meanings?